# to get json from an api get call c#

Tags: c#, rest, api

I want to get a JSON from an API Get Call, the code is hitting right on the 
server and getting the data succesfully but it is getting me some HTML with 
json. I want only the json and to use it.
i have also hitted that link from postman but and selected json but it gives 
me this:-

> Unexpected '<'

my code for calling an api :-

```
string Baseurl = "http://**********.******.net/";
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    List<Status> EmpInfo = new List<Status>();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("Help/Api/GET-api-Test-CheckStatus");
        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  
            EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Status>>(EmpResponse); //Error on this Line
        }
        return View(EmpInfo);
    }
}
```

when I am doing this it gives me this error on this line:-

```
EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Status>>(EmpResponse);
```

and the error is:-

> [JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 
>   <. Path '', line 0, position 0.]
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue() +1097
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() +103
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean 
>    hasConverter) +71
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
>   (JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) +489
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type 
>   objectType) +210
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, 
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings) +136
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, 
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings) +66
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value) +42
>   ConsumeHttpClient.Controllers.d__1.MoveNext() in 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
>   +99

Comment: It could be that you are hitting the webpage which also calls the API to get the data. If it is the correct, then you will have to read the data as XML and then extract the data from it as JSON.

Comment: Also, it would be more helpful if you can put the sample response here

Comment: it is giving me an html page in this line :-                                            
EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Status>>(EmpResponse);